# JBoss 7.1 and Hibernte 4.3.5 cause exception

Tags: jboss7.x, hibernate-4.x

I create a project with Hibernate 4.3.5 and JBoss 7.1.1.
I give you a screenshot about the composition of my project:

[image]

The jars on `WEB-INF/lib` are:

[image]

Bellow, are the rquired classes:

```
EntityDao.java
```

```js
public class EntityDao implements EntityDaoInterface<Book, Integer>
{
 private Session currentSession;
 private Transaction currentTransaction;

 public EntityDao() {
 }

 public Session openCurrentSession() {
  currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
  return currentSession;
 }

 public Session openCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
  currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
  currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
  return currentSession;
 }
 
 public void closeCurrentSession() {
  currentSession.close();
 }
 
 public void closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
  currentTransaction.commit();
  currentSession.close();
 }
 
 private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
  StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
  SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
  return sessionFactory;
 }

 public Session getCurrentSession() {
  return currentSession;
 }

 public void setCurrentSession(Session currentSession) {
  this.currentSession = currentSession;
 }

 public Transaction getCurrentTransaction() {
  return currentTransaction;
 }

 public void setCurrentTransaction(Transaction currentTransaction) {
  this.currentTransaction = currentTransaction;
 }

 public void persist(Person entity) {
  getCurrentSession().save(entity);
 }

 public void update(Person entity) {
  getCurrentSession().update(entity);
 }

 public void delete(Person entity) {
  getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public List<Person> findAllPersons() {
  List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Person").list();
  return persons;
 }

 public Person findPersonById(Integer id) {
  Person person = (Person) getCurrentSession().get(Person.class, id);
  return person; 
 }
 
}
```

```
EntityDaoInterface.java
```

```js
public interface EntityDaoInterface<T, Id extends Serializable> 
{
 public void persist(T entity);
 public void update(T entity);
 public T findById(Id id);
 public void delete(T entity);
 public List<T> findAll();
 public void deleteAll();
}
```

```
EntityService.java
```

```js
public class EntityService 
{
 private static EntityDao entityDao;

 public EntityService() {
  entityDao = new EntityDao();
 }

 public void persist(Person entity) {
  entityDao.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
  entityDao.persist(entity);
  entityDao.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
 }
 
 public void update(Person entity) {
  entityDao.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
  entityDao.update(entity);
  entityDao.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
 }

 public void remove(Person entity) {
  entityDao.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
  entityDao.delete(entity);
  entityDao.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
 }

 public Person findPersonById(int id) {
  entityDao.openCurrentSession();
  Person person = entityDao.findPersonById(id);
  entityDao.closeCurrentSession();
  return person;
 }

 public List<Person> findAllPersons() {
  entityDao.openCurrentSession();
  List<Person> persons = entityDao.findAllPersons();
  entityDao.closeCurrentSession();
  return persons;
 }

 
 public void deleteAll() {
  entityDao.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
  entityDao.deleteAll();
  entityDao.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
 }

 public EntityDao entityDao() {
  return entityDao;
 }
}
```

```
Person.java
```

```js
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person
{
 @Id      
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
 private int id;
 
 @Column(name = "age")
 private int age;
 
 @Column(name= "name")
 String name;
 
 public Person() {}

 public Person(int id, int age, String name) {
  super();
  this.id = id;
  this.age = age;
  this.name = name;
 }

 // With the methods: set, get, toString, hashCode, equals
 
}
```

```
hibernate.cfg.xml
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=ccc</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">lm</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pp</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <mapping class="com.esprit.entity.Book"/>
    <mapping class="com.esprit.entity.Person"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

```
DataModelBeanD.java
```

```js
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DataModelBeanD implements Serializable 
{
    private List<Person> list;
    private Person person = new Person();
    private boolean edit;
    private EntityService entityService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
     entityService = new EntityService();
     list = entityService.findAllPersons();
    }
}
```

After running the project, the following error appears:

```js
08:32:54,297 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "HelloJPAHibernate.war"
08:33:01,282 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
08:33:01,290 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
08:33:01,293 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.service.allow_crawling=false, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}
08:33:01,297 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
08:33:01,317 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
08:33:01,318 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
08:33:01,366 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
08:33:01,453 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
08:33:01,455 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000401: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=ccc]
08:33:01,457 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=lm, password=****}
08:33:01,458 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
08:33:01,460 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 5 (min=1)
08:33:03,123 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
08:33:03,255 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/HelloJPAHibernate].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:936) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at com.esprit.dao.EntityDao.getSessionFactory(EntityDao.java:48) [classes:]
at com.esprit.dao.EntityDao.openCurrentSession(EntityDao.java:25) [classes:]
at com.esprit.dao.EntityService.findAllPersons(EntityService.java:86) [classes:]
at com.esprit.crud.dynamic.DataModelBeanD.init(DataModelBeanD.java:37) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
```

I couldn't know what's missed, could you please help me solving this issue. Any proposition is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by making Hibernate 4.2.21 instead of Hibernate 4.3.5. Then I re-create the method `getSessionFactory()` of the class `EntityDao.java` like bellow:

```js
private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()      
 {
  if (sessionFactory == null) {
         Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
         ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
         registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
         ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();
          
         sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);           
     }
  return sessionFactory;
 }
```